# phpunit doesn't work on sublime text 3

Tags: phpunit, sublimetext3

In my Sublime Text 3 PHPUnit doesn't work. Bundle has installed correctly but plugin is inactive. Has anyone resolved the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: What PHPUnit plugin are you are using? Try PHPUnitKit https://github.com/gerardroche/sublime-phpunit, and if you have issues ping me on [twitter @gerardroche](https://twitter.com/gerardroche) or open an issue on the tracker. You can also install it via Package Control.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, there is a working ST3 version in the develop branch:

https://github.com/stuartherbert/sublime-phpunit/tree/develop

I got it to work by cloning the develop branch into my `{ST3}/Packages` folder and then restarting ST3.

At the time when I installed the plugin (a couple of months ago), the ST3 compatible version of sublime-phpunit was not available through Package Control, which is why I installed it with git.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try and will let you know if it helps. Thanks!